# Google Core IoT Device Offline Event or Connection Status

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-iot

Does anybody know of an easy way to trigger an event when a device on Google Core IoT goes offline?  Before I switched to Google's IoT implementation, this was ***very easily*** handled by triggering an event when MQTT disconnects, but it seems Google has no easy way of doing this.

Does anybody know if there is something planned for this?

***Who's back do I need to scratch to get them to see that something like this is a basic requirement for IoT device management!***

Other platforms like AWS and Microsoft already have this implemented (or some way to handle it easily):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html

[Device connectivity(online/offline)status with the Auzure iot hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438490/device-connectivityonline-offlinestatus-with-the-auzure-iot-hub)

I wish I had known this before writing all my code and implementing my setup using Google's IoT platform, I guess that's my fault for assuming something ***so simple*** and that should be standard for IoT devices would be available.

How are you going to compete with other IoT providers if you can't even provide basic offline/online events?!

My reply in this SO question shows how I had to write 100+ lines of code just to create a firebase function to check if a device is online (but that still doesn't handle offline events, and is just a hack for something that ***should be native to ANY IoT service provider***!):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54609628/378506

I'm hoping someone else has figured out a way to do this, as i've spent numerous days searching SO, Google, Google Core IoT Documentation, and still have not found anything.

Even if MQTT Last Will was supported we could make that work, but even that IS NOT SUPPORTED by Google (https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/requirements) ... come on guys!

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen okay but that's specific to firebase, I need something like that for Google Core IoT devices

Comment: By the use of your other SO question I assume you're device is using Firebase. I'm not a Java dev so I didn't put an answer, but I would use whatever event stream or notification channel you have (in JS it would be an rx Observable or Subject) and write an event provider based on online/offline state?

Comment: @DennisSmolek that's the problem though, removing firebase from having anything to do with this... there's no way to determine when a device goes offline -- i was referencing Firebase as that's what I used to manually check the device status by comparing timestamps for the device (or sending command and checking response)

Comment: So I basically have to run that function EVERYTIME my app is loaded, or page is changed, to make sure the device has not gone offline.  Even if they just added LWT to MQTT implementation I could come up with a way to trigger a pub/sub and update the db to mark it as offline .. but right now Google has NOTHING for this which I really just can't fathom why they don't

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your cloud project does have access to the individual MQTT connect/disconnect events, but currently they only show up in the Stackdriver logs. Within the cloud console, you can create an exporter that will publish these events to a Pub/Sub topic:

1. Visit the [Stackdriver Logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs) in the
   Cloud Console.
2. Enter the following advanced filter:

   ```
   resource.type="cloudiot_device"
   jsonPayload.eventType="DISCONNECT" OR "CONNECT"
   ```
3. Click **CREATE EXPORT**
4. Enter a value for **Sink Name**
5. Select **Cloud Pub/Sub** for **Sink Service**
6. Create a new Cloud Pub/Sub topic as the **Sink Destination**

The exporter publishes the full [LogEntry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry), which you can then consume from a cloud function subscribed to the same Pub/Sub topic:

```
export const checkDeviceOnline = functions.pubsub.topic('online-state').onPublish(async (message) => {
  const logEntry = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(message.data, 'base64').toString());
  const deviceId = logEntry.labels.device_id;

  let online;
  switch (logEntry.jsonPayload.eventType) {
    case 'CONNECT':
      online = true;
      break;
    case 'DISCONNECT':
      online = false;
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error('Invalid message type');
  }

  // ...write updated state to Firebase...

});
```

Note that in cases of connectivity loss, the time lag between the device being unreachable and an actual `DISCONNECT` event could be as long the MQTT keep-alive interval. If you need an immediate check on whether a device is reachable, you can send a command to that device.

Comment: Devunwired -- you sir are a godsend! Thank you thank you thank you thank you!! Works perfectly, this is amazing!!

Comment: For those coming here trying to solve the problem, devunwired is missing a step. You must enable at least "Info" logging for your IoT Core registry. Go to IoT Core > Registries > [your registry] > Edit Registry > Select "Info" log level > Click save.

Comment: Stackdriver logs sometimes does not keep order. In case `DISCONNECT` followed by `CONNECT` event, sometimes Stackdriver logs `CONNECT` first  then `DISCONNECT`. Firebase status does not match the actual state. Any idea for avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i think is that

```
We need 3 things
  cloud sheduler ,
 and 2 cloud functions
```

The first function will be the @devunwired answer but  instant of

```
// ...write updated state to Firebase... schedule a second function to trigger in 2-3 min (let device to recconect)
```

the seccond function will send a command to device

```
if the device resposne to command
     if stored status is connected dont do nothing 
     else if the stored status is disconnected then update the status to connected and do what ever you want maybe email 
else 
     if stored status is disconnected dont do nothing 
     if stored status is connected change the status alert by email or something
```