# iot-smart-home-cloud (gcp project) I can run commands in flutter app. But I can't run Voice(AOG) smarthome commands

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I've been trying to finish the project below for four months. It will serve as the basis for a new project of mine that will use **Android things/Firestore** and raspberry pi 3 in the back-end (and not cloud iot core/Mqtt/Esp32
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iot-smart-home-cloud
I can send commands via (client) flutter app (as pictured photo999). But I can't do the same using the actions on google console simulator. I need help to use
Stackdriver logs/error and/or chrome://inspect

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fyc7mVi3cjNK-QddfKtmLgdXkcKpUqdC?usp=sharing

**I tried this:** [Google Core IoT Device Offline Event or Connection Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54609757/google-core-iot-device-offline-event-or-connection-status)  by  ***devunwired*** But it didn't help me solve the issue

Comment: Have you followed all of the steps including account linking through the Google Assistant?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/neuberfran/6d297d359e52dd35b086fd3d546ea770

Yes, @Nick Felker

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qcxBln9DoaCFB54GXl93kjoeXeLGSXaE
I create firebase-hosting-app where I can see device-configs/devices (collections) from firestore. But in devices (collection) of the firestore I can't do changes(using flutter app). Question 01:  Will changes to the devices collection be made via voice or via mqtt messages? 
Question 02: Is the fulfillment.onSync method not being called to register devices in the Google Home app(after Account linking)?

Comment: Seems like the 404 link should go to [the test page](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/testing). Do your devices appear in the Google Home app after linking?

Comment: @NickFelker No. My devices not appear in Home app in the traditional way that should appear for me to put the devices in a certain room. The most I can get is the screen below: (which I already posted on the previous answer link) : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GTewep7PVQiygBxJ4VzV_ui6yg6iqxt8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @NickFelker The only thing I can do on the screen of the link above is to delete the device by clicking on the trash can. This will obviously change the devices and device-configs collection in Firestore. Question 01: Did you develop this project?

Comment: Okay then you have not completed the account linking step. I did not develop the project, but it appears though you've missed a step.

Comment: @NickFelker I followed all the steps of this project in the github readme (I'm sure) and I have no issues in the cloud functions log. Do you have this project running on your machine(Google Home app) ? Which step(s) do you think is missing for me?

Comment: @NickFelker I have news. According to photo775, instead of putting link-account I was putting login (word)  in authorization url(I don't know why). Now, I have issue of the photo776.  I also developed this project: https://github.com/shivasiddharth/google-actions-smarthome, as per photo777. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZH7nZInvHchw-gtJSDVFd_1qzBzFgiXx?usp=sharing

Comment: In the Google Home app you should connect to your service and sync devices. You should know it worked if your devices appear in the Google Home app and can be controled.

Comment: I need integrate this project: https://github.com/hoobs-org/homebridge-google/blob/master/portal/src/app/link-account/link-account.module.ts (link-account folder) with the project of this issue. to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in 25.12. In fact, according to the photo, I was putting the clientId and clientSecret fields incorrectly. They were different in the angular application (environment) and in the actions on google (Account linking/Settings). I matched them and solved them:

[image]