# How check my device is connected (IOTCore - GCP)

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, sdk

I have an registry with multi device in IoT Core (Google Cloud Platform). It's possible check connectivity of one device with SDK java?

Comment: Does this work for you? https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/quickstart#run_a_nodejs_sample_to_connect_a_virtual_device_and_view_telemetry

Comment: Nop. In this link we have an simulator for device, generate keys and add devices. I needed check the connectivity of my device (programmatically) - JAVA.

Comment: This post might help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54609757/google-core-iot-device-offline-event-or-connection-status

Comment: Yes. It's awesome. Thank you!